# Struggling to make a decrypter in python

Tags: python

Hello i have an encrypted message i have opened the file in python created a list from the text document of all the individual characters, I then want to add a key to each letter in the list.

```
print (chr((ord(Z+key)))) # takes the ASCII value of the letter adds the key then changes back into a character
```

My issue is how do i made Z+1 Equal A instead of [

Comment: A straightforward way might start `if result > ord('Z'):`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use congruent addition!

```
key = 5
for i in range(26):
    print (chr((i + key) % 26 + ord('A')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment says. if result > Z. Then you count up more number to result so that is becomes a.

```
result = chr(ord(Z+key))
if result > ord(Z):
    result = chr(ord(Z+102))
```

i am not sure of it is 102 or 103.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way out is to view both the message and the keys as bytes.
Then you can just perform an exclusive-or (`^`) for both encryption and decryption.

If you need readable output, use `base64` encoding on the key and ciphertext before writing them to disk. You can use my [onepad](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/onepad) program as an example of this approach.